# C#でSQLServerへの接続

Tags: c#

SqlConnectionクラスのOpenメソッドを使用するのと､LinqToSQLでDBContextクラスを生成する方法とどちらかおすすめでしょうか｡

どちらでも接続方法はわかるのですが､違いをよく理解してないまま使うのも気持ち悪いので…
ご教授ください｡

Answer (score 6, accepted):

データベースエンジンへの接続は手段でしかなく、真の目的はデータベース操作（データ取得 and/or データ操作）にあるはずです。

というわけで接続した後で何をしたいのでしょうか？ 固定的なSQL文を発行するだけでいいのであれば`SqlConnection`クラス及び`SqlCommand`クラスを使用することになりますが、[O/R Mapper](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)を使いたいのであればライブラリが用意されています。
ただし、`LinqToSQL`は.NET 3.5での初登場からほぼほぼ放置されており、なおかつ.NET 3.5 SP1にて[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/data/ef.aspx)という別のライブラリが登場しています。こちらは随時、機能追加・バージョンアップを重ねています。もし`LinqToSql`を検討されているのであればそれよりは`Entity Framework`をお勧めします。

Comment: Entityframeworkがおすすめですか！昔、すこし勉強した事ありますが、実際の実装はした事ありませんでした。 勉強してみます！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

何をやりたいのかによって最適な手段はことなってきます。

ADO.NETによる接続であればSQLを直接記述するので、SQL Serverの機能を余すところなく利用できます。

LINQ To SQLはSQL Serverのスキーマを元にクラスを自動生成する簡易的なORマッパーです。SQLを直接記述する事も出来ますが、原則として自動生成されるSQLを使うことになるので非効率なSQL文が生成される事もあるでしょう。静的型のチェックによる恩恵もあるのでADO.NETに比較してコーディングは楽になるでしょう。

Entity Frameworkはクラス設計を元にSQL Serverのスキーマを生成するORマッパーです。先にクラス設計を行うので既存のデータベースに対して利用するのは難しいです。また逆にEntity Frameworkを使わずにSQL Serverにアクセスする必要が生じた場合に苦労するかもしれません。

Comment: Entity Frameworkは既存のデータベースを基にモデル生成を行う`Database First`をサポートしています。その後の機能追加でクラス設計から行う`Code First`もサポートされました。

Comment: 個人的にはDB設計を先にしたいのでEntityFrameworkが有効みたいですね！参考になりました。 お二人の回答に本当に感謝しております。

Answer (score 0):

お二人の回答とても参考になりました。
LinwToSqlが個人的には簡単でいいな、と思っていたのですが、EntityFrameworkも勉強して使えるようにしたいと思います。

貴重な回答とお時間、ありがとうございました。

Comment: これは回答ではありません。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参照の上、対応してください。